# how to get token from Tableau Server trusted Authentication?

Tags: server, tableau-api

I'm trying to get a tableau server trusted authentication token for authorization.
I'm requesting the post method to the tableau server.

```
https://example.server.name/trusted/username=admin?&target_site=Sales
```

Is it a corrected way to get the trusted token from the tableau server?
or I missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to whitelist your trusted server using the  [tsm authentication](https://help.tableau.com/current/server-linux/en-us/trusted_auth_trustIP.htm) command

And the ? is misplaced in the URL. Should be

```
https://example.server.name/trusted?username=admin&target_site=Sales
```